# Is table talk acceptable in tournament play?

Tags: etiquette, tournament

I'm interested in playing boardgames competitively. I want to know if there are any unwritten rules or written rules when the stakes are high.

I'm really concerned that cross talk (conversation between two players) can promote collusion in a multiplayer game. What are the common rules on table talk for tournaments? Can you point me in the direction of good resources on tournament etiquette or examples therein? For instance, poker tournaments have their own traditional social mores (most of which I don't know or understand). Are there any similarities to board games?

Comment: I imagine that tournament regulations would be the arbiter of what, if any, kind of tabletalk is allowed.

Comment: Some games (e.g. 30 Seconds, Diplomacy) are about talking. Some allow trading or negotiation (Catan). In some games, all players have access to the same information while in other games one or more players have more information than others. A good answer would have to account for all these factors and I think it would be too broad to try and put everything in a single answer. Maybe try to look into a single game first?

Comment: Your answer is going to depend not only on the game itself but the tournament also. As they get more serious the rules get stricter. What may be acceptable at a casual tournament may not be at a pro tournament.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. From what I've read so far the rules are specific to each tournament, it depends whether it's Catan, Chess or Scrabble. I'll get there and find out for myself. Thanks again.

Comment: The question may be too broad for the SE format, but you can try a forum like [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/forums/region/1/boardgamegeek) for help.

Comment: Find a game you are interested in and then repost for that game